# Let $A$ be a subring of $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ which properly contains $\Bbb{Q}$, then $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ is finitely genrated $A$ module. (True/False)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modules

I think this is true. As $A$ properly contains $\Bbb{Q}$, there is a polynomial $f(X)\in A$ with dergee $\ge1$. I have to prove $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ is finitely generated as $A$ module i.e. $\exists f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\in Q[X]$ such that for all $g\in\Bbb{Q}[X]$, $g=h_1f_1+\cdots+h_nf_n$ for some $h_1,\ldots,h_n\in A$.

Can anyone suggest me a wayout to prove this? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb Q[X] = A[X]$, so all you need is to find a monic polynomial in $A[t]$ which annihilates $X$.

Comment: Thanks I got it.